# HTML Href how to open a file as text

Tags: html

Is there a way to use
`<a href="test.html">test</a>`
but when clicked it opens the html file as a text file, like what happens when you open a css file in your browser

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the **file:///** protocol if you want to link to local files. So in your case paste file path with that three slashes.

Code Example:

```
<a href="file:///C:\test.html">test.html</a>
<a href="file:///C:\test.css">test.css</a>
```

I hope this will help you out if not, do let me know!

Comment: Thanks it works with html files, but when i try to do it with a php file it just opens it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you please explain, what do you mean by it just opens it. Is it like opens it empty or with error?

Comment: When i use it with a php file it opens it as a normal php file would. it just shows everything , not the text. I am using a server/vps

Comment: Can you please try php file with this protocol " file://" two slashes only, i hope it will work.

Comment: it still just redirects me to the actual php page

Comment: Now that ive looked further file:// which for me is domain.com///test.html gives me the actual page, not the code

Comment: Did you get the php solution?